# Which additional drivers should I enable?

Tags: software-installation, nvidia-geforce, additional-drivers

Which driver should I select under "Additional Drivers"? The command  `ubuntu-drivers-devices` shows that my model is: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]. Also it shows "driver : nvidia-375 - distro non-free recommended". By default, I have the X.Org X server drivers installed. I assume that the right thing to do would be to select the recommended NVIDIA drivers, right?

Another question I have is that there is also an option under "Unknown: Unknown". Should I select the Processor microcode firmware or leave it as it is and don't use it?

Please consider the fact that I will be playing Steam games (Rocket League - to be more specific).
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

[image: Software & Updates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendations for proprietary graphics drivers for your Lenovo Y50 laptop are as follows.

1. Install *nvidia-375* because it is recommended. Also install NVIDIA X Server Settings tool for configuring the NVIDIA Linux driver from a GUI application. Values such as brightness and gamma, XVideo attributes, temperature, and OpenGL settings can be queried and configured via nvidia-settings.

   ```
   sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings  
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. For the *intel-microcode* package, I let the Ubuntu installer make the decision for me when installing Ubuntu. If the Ubuntu installer installed intel-microcode automatically I recommend keeping it, otherwise I do not recommend installing intel-microcode afterwards. My objective is to keep your system simple in order to avoid vexing problems troubleshooting a possible boot failure following a proprietary graphics driver installation or update.

Answer (score 2):

As you say you are going to play games, it is recommended to install and use the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, the latest stable drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch are `nvidia-375`.
You can install them by executing the following command : `sudo apt install nvidia-375`

Please note that there is currently an issue with these drivers when waking up the computer from suspense. But if you don't use the suspend feature, the drivers are working as expected. You can find many questions on Ask Ubuntu which are related to this topic, a later on update might fix this.

`intel-microcode` option lets you use newer firmware for the intel CPU - to install it execute :
`sudo apt install intel-microcode` It is not necessary to install it, but to some extend it is recommended, because otherwise you use the old firmware that came with the shipped BIOS.

Note : To make use of the newly installed drivers and firmware, you have to reboot the system.
Necessary additional packages such as `nvidia-prime` (if you have a notebook with NVIDIA Optimus support) and `nvidia-settings` are getting installed automatically with the drivers.
If this for whatever reason does not happen, you can just install them manually afterwards.